# How to Delphi "Custom Title Bar for VCL Forms" Add caption or glyph to custom button?

Tags: delphi, vcl

I'm using onPaint event handler on the custom button, but i don't know what to write to source an image list or add a caption to this button.

```
 procedure TForm1.TitleBarPanel1CustomButtons0Paint(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   ...
 end;
```

Comment: Consider not using customized title bars.

Comment: If you go to this link you will see that its described but without code examples
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Custom_Title_Bar_for_VCL_Forms

Comment: I know. I have also tried it but gave up because it wasn't very straight-forward. Still, my point is: don't use customized title bars at all.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Why to consider not using it?! its the official solution, I just need help how to approach it!

Comment: Because you will run into many bugs. Although this is the official solution given by Embarcadero, it's not really a Microsoft-endorsed technique. My experience is that customized title bars leads to a ton of bugs related to painting, moving windows (using mouse, keyboard, Aero snap, ...), remote desktop, screen readers and other accessibility tools, high DPI, per-monitor DPI scaling, keyboard interface.

Comment: For instance, the first thing I did when I had installed RAD Studio 10.3 (or 2, don't remember) was to maximize the IDE window by dragging the title bar to the top of the screen (which invokes Aero snap). And then the IDE became maximized, but the title bar's search edit box was displaced half a centimetre downwards, and the title bar caption randomly moved a few pixels every now and then. Normally, if I see that behaviour in a software application my reaction is to never use any software from that manufacturer again!

Comment: @Andreas I can't resist: *Normally, if I see that behaviour in a software application my reaction is to never use any software from that manufacturer again!* cont. ... but due to abnormal circumstances .... ;)

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Quite true. I have been using Win32 and Delphi for more than 20 years and I don't have any motivation to learn any other platform or language, so I am really happy that Embarcadero is keeping Delphi alive (even if I tend to be rather vocal about the IDE's recent quality issues).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Similar Delphi history here (Delphi 2 first purchase, which came with Delphi 1 too) and although looking into other tooling too, I always return to the well known toolbox called Delphi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this event handler, `Sender` is actually a `TSystemTitlebarButton`. You can cast it to access his properties such as the `Canvas`. Having the `Canvas`, you can draw whatever is needed.

Simple use example:

```
procedure TForm1.TitleBarPanel1CustomButtons0Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
   (Sender as TSystemTitlebarButton).Canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10);
end;
```